# Exactly why is a(t) = (t^3, t^2) is not an immersion? What do the vectors in the image of Da(t) look like?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $\alpha:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be a differential mapping defined by $\alpha(t) = (t^3, t^2)$. I'm pretty sure I understand why $\alpha(t)$ is not an immersion, but I really want to make sure I understand in more than just a hand-wavy sort of way. So please let me know if my reasoning here is correct:

The differential of $\alpha$, $D\alpha(t)$, is given by the column vector:

$$\begin{align}
D\alpha(t)=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        3t^2 \\
        2t \\
        \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}$$

But the elements of $T_{t}\mathbb{R}$ are just scalars, correct? So then picking some $v\in T_{t}\mathbb{R}\subset \mathbb{R}$, we have:

$$\begin{align}
D\alpha(t)[v] = 
        \begin{bmatrix}
        3t^2v \\
        2tv \\
        \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}.$$

If my above reasoning is correct, then it is clear that at $t=0\in \mathbb{R}$, $D\alpha(t)$ maps all vectors in $T_{t}\mathbb{R}$ to the zero vector, $\textbf{0}\in T_{\alpha(t)}\mathbb{R}^2$, so then $D\alpha(t)$ is not injective $\forall t\in \mathbb{R}$ so $\alpha$ is not an immersion.

Comment: Exactly. On top of this, it is not even possible to find a reparametrization of $a$ that would produce an immersion

Comment: Great, thanks! By the same reasoning above then, the mapping a(t)=t^3-4t, t^2-4) is an immersion since Da(t) is an injective linear transformation, but is not an embedding since a is not a homeomorphism between R and a(R), since a(2) = a(-2)?